# how to print text from textField in label programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i like to print textField Value in label by clicking button key. but i have been unable to do it. below is codes

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {


 override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()


view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
setupLabel()
setupTextField()
setupButton()
}

func setupLabel() {

let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)
label.text = "welcome to my world"
label.textColor = UIColor.yellow
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.layer.borderWidth = 2
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.addSubview(label)
}

func setupTextField() {

let textField = UITextField()
textField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width:   self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 60)
textField.placeholder = "text here"
textField.textAlignment = .center
textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.addSubview(textField)
 }

 func setupButton() {

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, height: 60)
button.setTitle("Enter", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, for: .normal)
button.layer.borderWidth = 2
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTarget), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(button)
  }

  func buttonTarget() {


// i  missed of here

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here you need to follow two steps

> you need to create the label and textfield in globally not instance, for e.g

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController
  let label = UILabel()
  let textField = UITextField()
```

hide the instance vale of your allocation

```
  func setupLabel() {

//let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)
label.text = "welcome to my world"
label.textColor = UIColor.yellow
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.layer.borderWidth = 2
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.addSubview(label)
}
```

then you can access the value directly anywhere in your class

```
func buttonTarget() {

 if let text = textField.text
    {
        label.text = text
    }

}
```

Comment: hellow brother please come to this link to help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell/48971060#48971060