# How to detect one button in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

How to detect one button in `UITableviewCell`, I have 10 `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell`, next when I click on `UIButton`  then it detects multiple buttons, (as like odd number list). my `UITableView` is with paging enabled. Here is my all code.

**TableView**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

 let mainArray = [["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"],["9","10","11","12"],["13","14","15","16"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.homeTableView.delegate = self
        self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return mainArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainArray[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.size.height
    }
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bookMarkBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bookMarkBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

        if(sender.isSelected == true)
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"favorite_blue"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"favorite_white"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the view, with a description of what you mean by "it detects multiple buttons, (as like odd number list)."

Comment: @Sam i do not have enough point so could not screenshot

Comment: @Sam give me mail address then i send to you the project

Comment: You can add a screenshot, but it won't embed the image inline, it'll only allow you to add link.

Comment: @Sam give the link please. where i add a screenshot

Comment: use http://imgur.com

Comment: @sam too slow is speed of internet in my place. so could not work in imgur.com

Answer (score 1):

To detect a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell`, you can follow any of the below approaches:

**1. Use `UIButton` `IBOutlets`**

You can create an `IBOutlet` corresponding to each `UIButton` in the `UITableViewCell` and use those outlets to identify which button action is performed.

**Example:**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if sender === button1
        {
            //button1 specific code here
        }
        else if sender === button2
        {
            //button2 specific code here
        }
        //and so on..
    }
}
```

**2. Use `UIButton` `Tag` property**

You can provide a `tag` value to each of the `UIButton` present in the `UITableViewCell` and then use that tag to identify the specific button.

**Example:**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if sender.tag == 1
        {
            //button1 has a tag = 1
            //button1 specific code here
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2
        {
            //button2 has a tag = 2
            //button2 specific code here
        }
        //and so on..
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

For setting different images in selected/unselected state of UIButton, you can use storyboard for that:

**For Unselected state:**

[image]

**For Selected state:**

[image]

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Let me know your complete problem statement and add some screenshot if possible.

Comment: please look to my question. there i am not use buttons like you

Comment: there i am used 2d array

Comment: Do you want to know in which UITableViewCell is the button pressed?

Comment: i want to set image in UIButton . there will be two image between selected and unSelected. please look my code again, next try to help me. please

Comment: Your code is nowhere using the 2d array for that purpose. And for setting image when selected/unselected, you can use the storyboard instead.

Comment: i will load json data with infinite scroll. so there i used `let arrayProductList = [[Product]]()`

Comment: I'm not getting what exactly you want to do with that 2d array in terms of setting the image.

Comment: i have to Favorite Button in all page

Comment: i edited my question, so please try to look at my question

Comment: Yes because I still don't understand your requirement completely.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAt` method, do add tag number to the buttons

```
cell.bookMarkBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then

```
@IBAction func bookMarkBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if(sender.tag == 0)
    {
        ...
    } else if (sender.tag == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create protocol

```
 protocol HomeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func bookMarkBtnTapped(btn: UIButton)
 }


class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var bookMarkBtn: UIButton!

   //add delegate var for protocol
   var delegate: HomeTableViewCellDelegate?

   @IBAction func bookMarkBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if(sender.isSelected == true)
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"favorite_blue"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"favorite_white"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    //set this which button is pressed
    self.delegate?.bookMarkBtnTapped(btn: sender)
   }
}
```

HomeViewController implement HomeTableViewCellDelegate method

```
class HomeViewController: HomeTableViewCellDelegate {

     func bookMarkBtnTapped(btn: UIButton) {

 //        here btn is book mark button tapped by user from tableview cell
     }
}
```

Comment: Now what issue you are facing?

Comment: i edited my question for better understand please look for it

Answer (score -1):

Use button tag for this.

In tableViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.bookMarkBtn.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.bookMarkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. bookMarkBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}



@objc func bookMarkBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {
   if sender.tag == 0 { //or which indexpath do you want. 
     //code 
   } else if sender.tag == 1 {
    //code
   }  
  ..
 }
```

remove `@IBAction func bookMarkBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton)` from tableviewcell class

Comment: But the button is being handled by the cell, not the view controller. Please see the code in the question.

Comment: Ankur please try to make it correct according rmaddy

Comment: I did this method twice today, worked for me. Could you please add some more details what actually going on after adding these line?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry add this method for pagination add look how to work `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.size.height
    }` i think that you can do it . so please try one more time